# Typing a CommonJS module that exports a function constructor with static methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a declaration file for [`minimal-bit-array`](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/minimal-bit-array). Here's its essence:

```
function A() { this.data = 'foo'; }

A.prototype.serialize = function() { /* ... */ };

module.exports = A;
module.exports.deserialize = function(x) { /* ... */ };
```

How do I type this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how:

```
declare module "a" {
  namespace A {
    export interface X { /* ... */ }
  }

  interface A {
    data: string;
    serialize(): A.X;
  }

  const A: {
    new (): A;
    deserialize(obj: A.X): A;
  };

  export = A;
}
```

This counter-intuitive `namespace` + `interface` + `const` sandwich gets successfully merged into an unambiguous *something* that TypeScript can understand. Consumption example:

```
import * as A from "a";

const a: A         = new A();
const d: A['data'] = a.data;
const x: A.X       = a.serialize();
const amazing      = A.deserialize(x);
```

Why the sandwich?

Theoretically, `namespace A` and `const A` are doing the same thing: describing `module.exports` of `a`. But the constructor - `new (): A` - can be declared only in an interface, while the TypeScript-only stuff - `interface X` - can be defined only in a namespace. That's why both are needed at the same time. There's no way to export `interface X` otherwise. At least as far as I know. Thankfully, TypeScript knows how to merge them.

In the meanwhile, `interface A` is just a convenience. When referencing `A` somewhere in the code in a context where a type would be expected, this is the interface that you get. The other two - `namespace` and `const` - aren't types, so there's no ambiguity. Could keep it in `namespace A`, however, if this is too much magic, and reference it as `A.A`.

Tested on 2.8.

#### Update

A slightly cleaner approach:

```
declare module "a" {
  namespace A {
    export interface X { /* ... */ }
  }

  class A {
    static deserialize(obj: A.X): A;
    data: string;
    constructor();
    serialize(): A.X;
  }

  export = A;
}
```

Classes happen to fit this scenario nicely. This is semantically equivalent to the original approach too, since classes are essentially syntactic sugar on top of functions. Check [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=module.exports%20%3D%20class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20deserialize(obj)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20this.data%20%3D%20'foo'%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20serialize()%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) to see what an implementation of the class above would get transpiled into.

Tested on 2.8.